# Organizing Latex macro file

Tags: org-mode, latex

I'm looking for a way to organize and share my LaTeX macros file. Ideally, I would like to write an org-mode file to export

- as a documentation file in html or pdf for sharing
- as a bare macros.tex containing only the macros

For instance, the org-file would look like

```
* Number sets

lorem ipsum

#+BEGIN_SRC latex
\def\R{{\mathbf R}}
\def\C{{\mathbf C}}
\def\N{{\mathbf N}}
#+END_SRC
```

The output in LaTeX would contain only

```
\def\R{{\mathbf R}}
\def\C{{\mathbf C}}
\def\N{{\mathbf N}}
```

The output in html would display

> **Number sets**
>
> Lorum ipsem
>
> ```
> \def\R{{\mathbf R}}
> \def\C{{\mathbf C}}
> \def\N{{\mathbf N}}
> ```

Any idea ?

Comment: Look up `tangling` in the Org mode manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Thanks. The solution is

```
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :tangle yes :exports code
\def\R{{\mathbf R}}
\def\C{{\mathbf C}}
\def\N{{\mathbf N}}
#+END_SRC
```

When using the function *org-babel-tangle* I get my bare .tex file and normal export function of org-more yields the html file.

Comment: BTW, you can [accept your own answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)  (assuming it works for you :-)). That is a good thing to do: it shows future visitors who might have the same or similar question that the answer actually answered the original question and therefore is a good bet to answer *their* question.